# The method pause() is undefined for the type Thread?

Tags: java, android

im new to Java can some please help me i cant identify activity super.pause();from biginig it was .OnPause .OnResume .. .. .. like that then i was pushted to change all to .pause .resume .. .. .. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5N7W.jpg

public class CleaningActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash); 
}   Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer <21000){
                        sleep (100);
                        logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                }
            startActivity(new Intent("com.iwilldothis.CLEARSCREEN"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();}
            finally{
                finish();
            }
        };


        protected void onStart() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.start();
            }

        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.resume();
            }

       protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.pause();
          }

        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.stop();
            } 

        protected void onDestroy() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.destroy();}
};
    }
```

Comment: Please post the entire class enclosing this, or at least the class declaration.

Comment: hope so you had solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Either the variable you're trying to invoke `pause()` on is not what you think it is. (Judging from your title, it is of type `Thread`.) Or, it is[`Thread.sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) that you're looking for.

Comment: or `Object.wait()` .. it depends what he wants to do.

Comment: That's something completely different and has to do with synchronization and locking though.

Comment: @Fancypant, Something is messed up: The class that is implementing `onPause` (I can't see the class name in the screen-shot) extends `Thread` it seems (it should presumably extend Activity judging from the methods you're implementing).

Comment: Try CleaningActivity.super.pause

Comment: @Fancypant, if an answer resolves your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the ✔.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Thread class has never had a `pause()` method, but it does have a `suspend()` method. However, that method has been deprecated almost since it was introduced as it has serious threading and deadlocking issues associated with it and should not be used.  You can read [Sun's Explanation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/jdk1.2/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) of why it is bad.

Comment: yes i know pause is not from java it is imported by android comands like start,resume,stop and destroy.

Comment: @Fancypant Right, but those callbacks from Android are there to allow your application to pause and resume its operations.  It doesn't have anything specifically to do with passing and resuming Threads.  The point is that you may need to store state that could be lost if the application terminates for some reason while it is paused.